# Cart Implementation using cookies

Tags: javascript, e-commerce, cart

I'm trying to implement a cart system by storing item ids in cookies and using them to generate items in the cart page but I'm having some difficulties and I need your help.
I need help implementing the logic to make the cart page functional

```
let cartContainer = document.getElementById('cartContainer');
let totalAmount = 0;
let cart = {}; // Store items in the cart
let itemCount = 0;

function dynamicCartSection(ob, quantity) {
  let itemId = ob.id;
  let itemCounter = cart[itemId] || quantity;

  let boxDiv = document.createElement('div');
  boxDiv.className = 'cart-item'; // Added class for styling
  cartContainer.appendChild(boxDiv);

  let boxImg = document.createElement('img');
  boxImg.src = ob.preview;
  boxDiv.appendChild(boxImg);

  let boxDetails = document.createElement('div');
  boxDetails.className = 'item-details'; // Container for name, amount, and quantity

  let boxh3 = document.createElement('h3');
  let h3Text = document.createTextNode(ob.name);
  boxh3.appendChild(h3Text);
  boxDetails.appendChild(boxh3);

  let boxh4 = document.createElement('h4');
  let h4Text = document.createTextNode('Amount: GHS ' + (ob.price * itemCounter).toFixed(2));
  boxh4.appendChild(h4Text);
  boxDetails.appendChild(boxh4);

  let quantityDiv = document.createElement('div'); // Container for buttons and quantity
  quantityDiv.className = 'quantity-container';

  let decreaseButton = document.createElement('button');
  decreaseButton.id = 'decreaseButton-' + itemId;
  decreaseButton.className = 'reduceQuantityButton';
  decreaseButton.innerText = '-';
  decreaseButton.onclick = function () {
    if (itemCounter > 1) {
      updateTotalAmount(-ob.price);
      updateCartItem(itemId, -1);
      // updateBadge();
      itemCounter--;
      quantityText.nodeValue = itemCounter; // Update quantity text
      h4Text.nodeValue = 'Amount: GHS ' + (ob.price * itemCounter).toFixed(2);
    } else {
      cartContainer.removeChild(boxDiv);
      updateTotalAmount(-ob.price * itemCounter);
      updateCartItem(itemId, -itemCounter);
      // updateBadge();
    }
  };
  quantityDiv.appendChild(decreaseButton);

  let quantityText = document.createTextNode(itemCounter); // Display the item quantity
  quantityDiv.appendChild(quantityText);

  let increaseButton = document.createElement('button');
  increaseButton.id = 'increaseButton-' + itemId;
  increaseButton.className = 'addQuantityButton';
  increaseButton.innerText = '+';
  increaseButton.onclick = function () {
    updateTotalAmount(ob.price);
    updateCartItem(itemId, 1);
    // updateBadge();
    itemCounter++;
    quantityText.nodeValue = itemCounter; // Update quantity text
    h4Text.nodeValue = 'Amount: GHS ' + (ob.price * itemCounter).toFixed(2);
  };
  quantityDiv.appendChild(increaseButton);

  boxDetails.appendChild(quantityDiv); // Add the quantity container to the boxDetails

  boxDiv.appendChild(boxDetails);

  updateTotalAmount(ob.price * itemCounter);
}

function updateTotalAmount(amount) {
  totalAmount += parseFloat(amount);
  let totalh4 = document.getElementById('toth4');
  if (totalh4) {
    totalh4.innerText = 'Amount: GHS ' + totalAmount.toFixed(2);
  }
}

function updateCartItem(itemId, quantity) {
  cart[itemId] = (cart[itemId] || 0) + quantity;
  itemCount += quantity;
  itemCount = Math.max(itemCount, 0); // Ensure itemCount is not negative
  document.getElementById("totalItem").innerHTML = ('Total Items: ' + itemCount);
  document.getElementById("badge").innerHTML = itemCount;

}


fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/products')
  .then(response => {
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
    }
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(data => {
    contentTitle = data.products; // Assuming that the products are inside a "products" property

    const orderIdValue = (document.cookie).split('=')[1]; // Extract the value after '='
    const orderIdArray = orderIdValue.split(','); // Split the values by commas

    // Filter out occurrences of "counter" and "0" from orderIdArray
    const filteredOrderIdArray = orderIdArray.filter(value => value !== "counter" && value !== "0");
    
    const counter = filteredOrderIdArray.length;

    document.getElementById("totalItem").innerHTML = ('Total Items: ' + counter);

    let totalAmount = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
      let itemCounter = 1;
      for (let j = i + 1; j < counter; j++) {
        if (Number(filteredOrderIdArray[j]) === Number(filteredOrderIdArray[i])) {
          itemCounter += 1;
        }
      }
      
      const itemId = Number(filteredOrderIdArray[i]);
      const item = contentTitle.find(product => product.id === String(itemId)); // Compare with string as per the response
      if (item) {
        totalAmount += parseFloat(item.price) * itemCounter;
        dynamicCartSection(item, itemCounter);
      }

      i += (itemCounter - 1);
    }
    updateTotalAmount(totalAmount);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('Fetch error:', error);
  });
```

This is my code for the cart.js

I've been trying to implement the logic but keep failing.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.